# ElasticSearch JS and React simple query from the code

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

This is what I created for fetching data from React application. Now I want to put all the items (only one in this case) into the JS object, so I could map the data on my webpge. How to merge queries and code to create a simple data object that represents data from the  ES query?

```
componentWillMount() {
var that = this;
client.search({
    index: 'products'
}).then(function (elasticResponse) {
    var hits = elasticResponse.hits.hits;

    that.setState({
        items: hits.map((hit) => ({
            name: hit._source.name,
            description: hit._source.description,
            imgUrl: hit._source.imgUrl,
            price: hit._source.price
        }))

    });

}, function (error) {
    console.trace(error.message);
});
```

}

This is the only item I put in ES
`{
        "_index": "products",
        "_type": "product",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "img": "http://writingexercises.co.uk/images2/randomimage/anchors.jpg",
          "title": "Breakfast",
          "author": "jill111",
          "price": 100
        }
      }`